# How wrap elements with jquery in different divs at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I wrap elements with jQuery. I have it working with different divs but wrapping only in to the `div` separate!

I have:

```
<section>
    <div class='parent'>

        <div class='child'></div>
        <div class='child'></div>
        <div class='child'></div>

    </div> 


    <div class='parent'>

        <div class='child'></div>
        <div class='child'></div>
        <div class='child'></div>

    </div> 

</section>
```

I want create another parent but if I use `wrapAll`, jQuery will wrap all elements from the two `div` elements in only one I want wrap in separate `div` elements.

**Result I need:**

```
<section>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='newParent'>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='newParent'>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
            <div class='child'></div>
        </div>
    </div> 

</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to wrap the child element groups, you could wrap all inner elements of the original parent nodes:

```
$('.parent').wrapInner('<div class="newParent">');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/fidajugivo/1/)

See also: [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

Comment: Well I need to add another jQuery method to my "don't forget these exist" list :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with one magic jQuery function, but you can come close:

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(this).children(".child").wrapAll($("<div/>", { "class": "newParent" }));
});
```

That finds each `.parent` element and then uses `.wrapAll()` to wrapp the child `.child` elements inside.

The `.wrap()` function differs in that it wraps *each* matched element separately.

*edit* — or just use `.wrapInner()` like a smart person.